# Use javascript value has HTML integer

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use the 'return' value from a JS function as a integer in HTML as follow:

HTML

```
<span class="..." data-from="..." data-to="<!--I want to use it here!-->" data-speed="..." data-refresh-interval="..."></span>
<!--Print the value here.-->
<div id="daysWorking"></div>
```

JS

```
<script>
    .
    .
    document.getElementById("daysWorking").innerHTML = Date.daysBetween(Jan1st2010, today);
  </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You would like to "grab" the value of `data-to` and use it in your function?

Comment: no, totally the opposite, I want to use the "daysWorking" value and use it as a `data-to` parameter. The JS functions is irrelevant, I need this value `Date.daysBetween(Jan1st2010, today)` as a parameter for `data-to`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand it well, but try

```
var foo = Date.daysBetween(Jan1st2010, today);
document.getElementById("daysWorking").innerHTML = foo;
document.getElementById('mySpan').setAttribute('data-to', foo);
```

where `mySpan` is the ID of your span.

If you don't care about old browsers, you can replace the third line of code with

```
document.getElementById('mySpan').dataset.dataTo = foo;
```

Comment: @AlexTarragó Doesn't matter very much. For example, `<span id="mySpan"></span><div id="daysWorking"></div>`.

Comment: @AlexTarragó See http://jsfiddle.net/c9zwY/. And better speak English so that others can understand, although you are the first catalan I have seen here :)

Comment: Solved! Thank you, _gràcies_ :)